# How to remove ordering of the levels from factor variable in R?

Tags: r, variables, r-factor

The title says it all, I ordered a factor variable when I generated it, now I would like to remove the ordering and use it as an unordered factor variable. 
And another question, if I use my factor variable as a predictor in a regression does it make a difference to R if it is ordered (ordinal) or simple factor variable (categorical)?

Comment: yes..What have you tried? for the second question, you can at least do some empirical tests..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

All you need is

```
x <- factor( x , ordered = FALSE )
```

e.g.

```
x <- factor( c(1,2,"a") , ordered = TRUE )
x
#[1] 1 2 a
#Levels: 1 < 2 < a

x <- factor( x , ordered = FALSE )
x
#[1] 1 2 a
#Levels: 1 2 a
```

Answer (score 3):

If you created your variable via `ordered`, it's as simple as resetting its class to `factor`.

```
f <- ordered(letters)
class(f) <- "factor"
identical(f, factor(letters))
```

In a *linear or additive* model (including linear regression, logistic regression and anything fit with `lm`, `glm` and `gam`) a factor predictor is treated exactly the same as an ordered predictor in terms of the overall model fit. You'll get the same predicted values, residuals, lack-of-fit statistics, etc regardless of which one you use.

However, the *contrasts* are different for the two classes. A factor uses treatment contrasts, ie the usual dummy-variable coding with a given level treated as the baseline. An ordered factor uses polynomial contrasts, which are based on orthogonal polynomials (whatever that means; I've never had a reason to use ordered factors). Because of this, the t-stats and P-values for individual coefficients will be different.

Comment: Yes, but I guess the result (interaction for ex:) that'll be shown will be based on which factor has the value "0", isn't it? So, basically, if you want to infer the effect of something w.r.t. a level, it makes sense to make it an ordered factor...

Comment: @Arun No, if you have a reference level you should use `relevel`.